# Using Cmake to add compiler options to existing cmake

Tags: cmake, build

I have a submodule with a CMakeLists.txt, which I would like to "amend" in a  way to make it work for my specific purpose (I need to add compiler flags and a different output directory) The output is a static library. My current approach is as follows:

I have a CMakeLists.txt in the root directory, which adds the submodule CMakeLists.txt via `add_subdirectory()` like so:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-my_needed_flags "
add_subdirectory(SubmoduleLibrary)
set_target_properties(SubmoduleLibrary PROPERTIES ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY output_folder)
add_custom_target(BuildLib)
add_dependencies(BuildLib SubmoduleLibrary)
```

Now this seems to work in some ways (the output directory is correctly chosen). But I get linker errors which I don't get when I compile the library adding the flags etc to the original CMakeLists.txt.
What is the correct way to build a library from an existing CMakeLists.txt with added parameters?

Comment: Ways for modifying a subproject always depend from the subproject itself. E.g. setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` would work if the subproject **appends** to that variable (with `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS } ...")`). But it won't work if the subproject **rewrites** the variable (like you do `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-my_needed_flags")`). Instead of setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` you could use [add_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) command: the subproject rarely would cancel the effect of this call.

Comment: *"I need to [choose a different] output directory. The output is a static library."* You're imho doing something wrong in this case. For your own cmake project there's no need to place the lib into a specific dir, since linking the cmake target cmake knows the exact path where the static lib will be placed. If you need to provide the lib for external use, the `install` functionality of cmake.

Comment: @fabian I will use install instead, thanks.